# DailyMotion Player API Being on commercial ad state

Tags: javascript, dailymotion-api

I'm using latest DailyMotion player api.
Is there any way to detect the fact that DM player now playing a DM commercial ad?

Right now I'm checking this by running 500ms setTimeout loop (as around 400ms is a gap between two timeupdate events) that checks if player is on playing state && timeupdate wasn't updated from the last time, then it means it's on commercial right now. But it's not perfect and there is 500-1000ms delay due to loop iteration time.

Answer (score 0):

to detect when the ad playing, you have to override the following method in your custom WebViewClient :

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Uri uri= Uri.parse(url);

    if (uri.getScheme().equals("dmevent")) {
        String event = uri.getQueryParameter("event");

        switch (event) {
            case "ad_start":

                // The ad has started playing

                break;
            case "ad_end":

                // The ad is over

                break;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
```

Here is where you will find some other usefull events : https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#player-api-events

Comment: Hello there, it was sime time whn i used DM api last time, i'm using Javascript player api, and i did not quiet understand what is `custom WebViewClient` can you give a little explanation?

Comment: was some time ago when*

Comment: My bad I thought you were on Android!
Sorry about that, my answer won't be of any help for you.